# Building a custom login form - encountering issues

Tags: login

I'm building a custom login form and I've tried two methods: `wp_authenticate()` and `wp_signon()`.

For the former, I am able to correctly return the `WP_User` object upon a successful authentication, but no cookies are set to signal to `is_user_logged_in()` that the user is indeed logged in. I suppose I can set my own cookies but is there an easier way?

For the latter, I keep having the error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`. I've tried calling the `wp_signon()` function from the `<head>`, the actual header, and in the page template. I see the same error regardless. I've looked online but I'm not seeing any solutions to this exact problem.

The specific error is pointing to line 7 of `base.php` - `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/www/mysite/current/web/wp/wp-content/themes/mysite/base.php:7)`.

But looking right there, I don't see any issue (these are lines 4 - 10, line 7 is the doctype):

```
use Roots\Sage\Wrapper;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

As per WP's own troubleshooting, I've checked that there are no extra spaces.

Regardless of how it's gone about, I just need to be able to log a user in with their credentials and have the ability to check their logged-in status to create a logged-in state on a website.

Any help?

Comment: It might be easier to style the existing login form than to build a custom one. That way you don't have to keep up with a bunch of different Core functions, just some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [authenticate filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate). This will handle everything for you.

```
function wpse_custom_login($user, $username, $password) {
    if (empty($username)) {
        $errors = new WP_Error();
        //add some error message, return $errors
    }
    $user = get_user_by('email', $username);
    // do some additional validation, checks, etc.
    return $user;
}
add_filter('authenticate', 'wpse_custom_login', 30, 3);
```

This is a really barebones example but begins to demonstrate how you would log in a user by email address instead of username.